# image not fading in using keyframes

Tags: html, css, css-animations, keyframe

I am trying to fade in an image using keyframes.  The problem I am having is that the image appears then disappears and then the keyframes start. Below is my html.

```
<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-2 col-sm-12">
  <img class="iphone_image" src="images/iphone6.png" alt="iphone-mockup">
</div>
```

and below is my css and keyframes:

```
.iphone_image {
  background-image: url("images/iphone6.png");
  width: 60%;
  transform: rotate(25deg);
  animation-name: image-appear;
  animation-duration: 10s;
  animation-delay: 5s;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in;
}
@keyframes image-appear {
  from {opacity:0;}
  to {opacity: 1;}
}
```

What I want to happen is when the web page loads there is a transition to when the image appears.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add `opacity: 0;` to the default state of the image:

```css
.iphone_image {
  background-image: url("images/iphone6.png");
  width: 60%;
  transform: rotate(25deg);
  animation-name: image-appear;
  animation-duration: 3s;
  animation-delay: 1s;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in;
  opacity: 0;
}

@keyframes image-appear {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-2 col-sm-12">
  <img class="iphone_image" src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/" alt="iphone-mockup">
</div>
```

Comment: Add `animation-fill-mode: forwards;` and also you can get rid of `from` keyframe.